# As of 0.10.1.0, how do you use monero-wallet-rpc?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc, monerod-commands, monero-wallet-rpc

Once updating to version 0.10.1.0, in addition to `monero-wallet-cli`, there is `monero-wallet-rpc`.  What is the difference in usage between the two?  What type of commands/arguments that were run previously with `monero-wallet-cli` should now be run instead with `monero-wallet-rpc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you previously ran `simplewallet` in CLI mode (or 0.10's `monero-wallet-cli` in RPC mode) then you would simply transition to using `monero-wallet-rpc` with the same flags. As always, running the binary with `--help` will give you a list of all possible flags.